# How to get the min-height of the object when its parent is set to display none?

Tags: jquery, each, css

Why I can't get the `min-height` of an object when its **parent** is set to `display: none`, but I still can it the object's height if the min-height is **not** in use?

For instance,

css,

```
li {
display:none;
}

.object {
display:block;
width:100px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

html,

```
<li><a href="#" class="object" style="height:200px;"><img class="element" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="object" style="min-height:300px;"><img class="element" /></a></li>
```

jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.object img').each(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().height());
    });

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5SDY/)

How can I still get the `min-height` of the object even though its parent is set to `display none`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When an element isn't displayed, it has no height or width.

You can extract the CSS attribute, though:

```
alert($(this).parent().css('min-height'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R5SDY/1/

Note that this now returns a string with "px" at the end, instead of a number like `height()` does. You may need to parse it as an integer:

```
alert( parseInt($(this).parent().css('min-height'),10) );
```

Obviously if there's no `min-height` set in CSS, this won't work. Depending on what you  want the number for, you may need to add some programmatic logic that extracts `.css('height')` if there's no min-height returned.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.object img').each(function(){
        var h = parseInt($(this).parent().css('min-height'),10) 
            || parseInt($(this).parent().css('height'),10);
        alert(h);
    });
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R5SDY/2/

Finally, remember that the values you're getting from `.css` aren't necessarily what the height will be when the element is finally displayed -- they're only what you *want* the height to be.

Comment: does it work the same if the min-height is in em, and not in px ?

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares Sure, but you may need to convert it to pixels depending on what you do with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.object img').each(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().css("min-height"));
});
```

that is just to get the css attribute, a hidden object has no height or width, so you'll need to display it, get the measurments and hide it.

something like the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/c2vrr/

please note that aslong as your DOM isn't 'huge' - it'll be instantanous, and you won't see the 'briefly displayed' elements.