# How to get minimum height in a varriable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting some height of my div from jquery. This height is changing time to time. How can I get its height minimum `200px` and maximum it can be any number.

```
$('#child_div').height( child_div_transfered_height );
```

I am getting "child_div_transfered_height" a number which is changing countiusely. I want to fix it minimum `200px`. How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the min-height of the object when its parent is set to display none?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773673/how-to-get-the-min-height-of-the-object-when-its-parent-is-set-to-display-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#child_div').attr('style','min-height:200px;');
```

Comment: i don't know why but its stoped my whole coding

Comment: child_div.style.transform = transform;
    child_div.style.oTransform = transform;
    child_div.style.msTransform = transform;
    child_div.style.mozTransform = transform;
    child_div.style.webkitTransform = transform;


    $('#child_div').height( child_div_transfered_width );
    $('#child_div').width( child_div_transfered_width );
    $('#child_div').attr('style','min-height:200px;');
    $('#child_div').attr('style','min-width:200px;');

Comment: its just adding min-height: 200px; in style tag of that div. But my div is still taking its height less than 200px

Comment: is there any option in jquery that it will strictly consider its min-height 200px for example in css we use "!important" for strictly using

Comment: actually its not a div its img tag. sorry for this

Comment: then instead of giving `child_div` as id,give your image id in the answer...i.e.
`$('#image_id').attr('style','min-height:200px;');`

Comment: its image id "child_div"

Comment: try this
`child_div.style.transform = transform; child_div.style.oTransform = transform; child_div.style.msTransform = transform; child_div.style.mozTransform = transform; child_div.style.webkitTransform = transform; $('#child_div').attr('style','min-height:200px;'); $('#child_div').attr('style','min-width:200px;');`

Answer (score 3):

set min-height using `.css()`:

```
$("#child_div").css("min-height", "200px");
```

Comment: i am getting "#child_div" width from "child_div_transfered_height" variable. It means "child_div_transfered_height" may be any number like 300,400 etc. if i am also adding your code in my code then its not working.

Comment: @user3319135:can you share the problem fiddle??

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#child_div").css("min-height", child_div_transfered_height);
```

Comment: i am getting "#child_div" width from "child_div_transfered_height" variable. It means "child_div_transfered_height" may be any number like 300,400 etc and minimum should be 200px. You are not using its minimum width 2oox